# View model & model are not communicating

Tags: swift, xcode, mvvm

I have added three separate files to this question. The first one is my model which has all of my var from my json data. The 2nd one is my View Model in which i've created a function to decode the data from json. the 3rd is my collection view controller that will display categories within the Json data. however, it does not seem as if my viewModel and model are communicating because when I am calling my VM inside of the Collections View controller, I am getting an error "Cannot find 'mealsCategories' in scope" which is linked to my VM -> Model. can anyone tell me why this is?

```
    struct MealCategoryResponse: Decodable {
        let  categories: [MealCategory]
    }
    struct MealCategory: Decodable {
        let category: String
        let image: String
        let description: String
    }
    enum CodingKeys3: String, CodingKey {
        case  category = "strCategory"
        case  image =  "strCategoryThumb"
        case description = "strCategoryDescription"
    }


    @MainActor
    class MealCatergoryViewModel: ObservableObject {
        
        @Published public var mealsCategories: [MealViewModel] = []
        
        private func loadCategories(strCategory: String) async {
        do {
            let mealCategoryResponse = try await
            JsonServiceRequest().parseData(url: Constants.Urls.mealsCategories)
        { data in
            return try?
            JSONDecoder().decode(MealCategoryResponse.self, from:data )
        }
            self.mealsCategories =
            mealCategoryResponse.categories.map(MealViewModel.init)
        } catch {
            print(ServiceError.decocorrupt)
            }
        }
    }
    struct MealViewModel: Identifiable {
        let id =  UUID()
        private let mealCategory: MealCategory
        init(_ mealCategory: MealCategory) {
            self.mealCategory = mealCategory
        }
        var category: String {
            mealCategory.category
        }
        var strCategoryThumb: URL? {
            URL(string: mealCategory.image)
        }
    }
```

Class file

```
import UIKit
class CatergoryCollectionCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var model: MealCatergoryViewModel = MealCatergoryViewModel()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Meals"
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return  1
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  mealsCategories.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "catergoryCell", for: indexPath) as! CatergoryCellCollectionViewCell
            cell.category.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)
         return cell
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showMeals" {
            if let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
                let MealCollectionViewController =  segue.destination as! MealCollectionViewController
                collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPaths[0],  animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any mealsCategories declared  in your collection view and I don't see where you initialize MealViewModel.

Comment: try: `model.mealsCategories.count` in `override func collectionView(...)`